# JQuery AddClass to sub element

Tags: jquery

I have this structure html

```
<ul class="footer_column">
    <li id="doc-22"><a href="/abc/index.php?id=22" title="wind blades coupling system" ><span>wind blades coupling system</span></a></li>
    <li id="doc-23"><a href="/abc/index.php?id=23" title="expandable bolt" ><span>expandable bolt</span></a></li>
    <li id="doc-24"><a href="/abc/index.php?id=24" title="security screw" ><span>security screw</span></a></li>
    <li id="doc-25"><a href="/abc/index.php?id=25" title="TH preload system " ><span>th</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to addClass to `<li id="doc-25"><a><span class="notranslate">th</span></a>`

Comment: $( "doc-25" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );

Comment: i guess the question is unclear . cant really get wat OP wants ??

Comment: $( "#doc-25 a span" ).addClass( "notranslate" )

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear. I am assuming you want to add class to `span`. Thus You can use `.find()`

```
$('li #doc-25').find('span').addClass('notranslate');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this and try if the `id` is static and will remain same...

```
 $( "#doc-25" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );
```

Comment: You are missing `#` in selector

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#doc-25').find('span').addClass('notranslate');
```

or

```
$('#doc-25 span').addClass('notranslate');
```

or

```
$("#doc-25").children('a').children('span').addClass( "class_to_add" );
```

or

```
$("#doc-25 > a > span" ).addClass( "class_to_add" );
```

References

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)